# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited (discord.py)

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, coroutine

(Сначала скажу что большАя часть кода скопирована)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = 'длинный'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def якот(ctx):
    print('Получена команда якот')
    ctx.send('Ок')
@bot.command(pass_context=True) #разрешаем передавать агрументы
async def test(ctx, arg): #создаем асинхронную фунцию бота
    await ctx.send(arg) #отправляем обратно аргумент

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

И ошибка

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited`
На команде 'якот'

Comment: Перед корутиной должно стоять ключевое слово `await`

Answer (score 1):

Любая корутина должна быть "ожидана". Это делается при помощи инструкции `await`.
Данный код будет правильным:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def якот(ctx):
    print('Получена команда якот')
    await ctx.send('Ок')
```